# Is it possible to convert this jquery chain returning a string into an array without a separate iteration?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML snippet like the following

```
<tr class="new">
<td>
   <input name="id" type="checkbox"/>
   <span>9</span>
</td>
<td> // Other Stuff... </td>
</tr>
// other table rows
<tr class="new">
<td>
   <input name="id" type="checkbox"/>
   <span>12</span>
</td>
<td> // Other Stuff... </td>
</tr>
```

CURRENTLY, a `.find('.new').find('input[name="id"]:checked').next().text().trim();` gives me a string like "912".

Is there anyway I can get back an array like [9,12] or ["9","12"] without having to explicitly iterate through the list of inputs returned back by the `.find` snippet? I am open to changing the query in order to avoid an iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
var arr = $('.new input[name="id"]:checked + span').map(function() {
            return $.trim((this).text());
          }).get();
```

If you want an array of numbers, just add a `+`, like this:

```
var arr = $('.new input[name="id"]:checked + span').map(function() {
            return +$.trim((this).text());
          }).get();
```

Comment: @Nick - Noob question: Does $('.new input[name="id"]:checked + span') optimizes my query and saves me from additional find() + next() traversals?

Comment: @papdel - yup, it finds `<span>` elements that are after the inputs :)

Comment: @Nick - also you are probably missing a $ before the this construct

Comment: @Nick - Could you also tell me how is the "+" converting the string into a number array? [Arrgh, I know so little about jquery]

Comment: @papdel - The `+` is JavaScript, the `.map()` just gets an array, the `+` converts each member into a number as it's added.

Comment: @Nick -Thanks for the previous comment. The query seems to work w/o calling the get() . Any particular reason that get() needs to be there?

Comment: @papdel - it gets a plain array, stripping off the jQuery properties...which isn't actually an array, it just behaves like one.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for jQuery's [`map` function](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
$(...).find('.new input[name="id"]:checked')
      .next()
      .map(function() { return parseInt($.trim($(this).text(), 10); })
      .get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @SLaks . I will probably accept Nick's answer as it saved me an extra query, apologies...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
myArray = new Array();

.find('.new').find('input[name="id"]:checked').each(function(){
    myArray.push($(this).next().text().trim());
});
```

Looks like .map() is probably the more sophisticated way to go though.

Comment: I always get my PHP and JavaScript arrays mixed up... that should do it.